# New WP_query in template not working with CPT+category on some pages

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, wp-query

I have three page templates, homepage, documentary, and corporate, each using the same CPT WP_query code with only the category name changed for each respectively. The homepage works fine, pulling and showing the correct category of my CPT. The other two do not work.

Here is a snippet of the code for the homepage:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage Reels
*/

/*
@package _tk
*/

get_header(); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<div class="entry-content">

    <div class="container-fluid">

    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'films',
                         'tax_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'film-type',
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => 'homepage',
                                            )
                                        ),
                         'posts_per_page' => '-1', );
          $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php /* Get the current post ID. */
                    $post_id = get_the_ID();
                  /* If we have a post ID, proceed. */
                    if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) { ?>

                    <div class="film_wrap col-md-4">

                        <?php // <h2 class="film_title"><?php the_title(); ?><?php //</h2> ?>

                        <?php $videourl = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'film_embed', true );
                              if ( $videourl != '' ) {
                                echo wp_oembed_get( $videourl ); 
                              } ?>

                        <?php if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'film_textarea', true ) ) : ?>
                            <div class="film_description">
                                <p><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'film_textarea', true ); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

                    <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', '_tk' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and the documentary template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Documentary Reels
*/

/*
@package _tk
*/

get_header(); ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<div class="entry-content">

    <div class="container-fluid">

    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'films',
                         'tax_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'film-type',
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => 'documentary',
                                            )
                                        ),
                         'posts_per_page' => '-1', );
          $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php /* Get the current post ID. */
                    $post_id = get_the_ID();
                  /* If we have a post ID, proceed. */
                    if ( !empty( $post_id ) ) { ?>

                    <div class="film_wrap col-md-4">

                        <?php // <h2 class="film_title"><?php the_title(); ?><?php //</h2> ?>

                        <?php $videourl = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'film_embed', true );
                              if ( $videourl != '' ) {
                                echo wp_oembed_get( $videourl ); 
                              } ?>

                        <?php if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'film_textarea', true ) ) : ?>
                            <div class="film_description">
                                <p><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'film_textarea', true ); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

                    <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', '_tk' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I have no errors via WP_DEBUG. Here is the testing site: http://thegallerymusic.com/test/

Can't think of what could possibly be allowing homepage to work, but causing the documentary/corporate templates to NOT work. Any ideas?

Comment: what doesn't work? It doesn't show anything? Also, can you add the names of the files?

Comment: Yea, on the corporate and documentary pages nothing shows up. The names of the template files are: homepage.php, corporate.php, and documentary.php. What's also interesting is that the archive page for the custom post type (http://thegallerymusic.com/test/films/) populates only six of the posts(two on page 2), out of twelve total. It's generating the containing `div`s for each post, but the custom_post_meta (the actual video embed, title, description) is not being loaded within those...

Comment: I think you need to show the code that is supposed to output the meta that you speak of.

Comment: Okay, I added the rest of the loop. It's identical for both pages, and, again, the homepage one shows every video in the correct category, while the documentary one (and corporate.php) does not.

Comment: you can get the post id with `get_the_ID()` function. Can you add the header where the name of the templates is?

Comment: Is $post_id actually populated in those other 2 templates? Output it - my guess is it's empty.

Comment: @TomásCot - I've updated the code with more of the header and replaced `$post_id->ID` with `get_the_ID()`. @vancoder - When I `var_dump($post_id);` it returns the correct id's of the posts.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but those meta fields (film_embed, film_textarea) _are_ actually populated for posts that have the documentary term applied - right? If you do `$custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); print_r($custom_fields);` you actually get something back?

Comment: Yes sir, @vancoder. I left the http://thegallerymusic.com/test/documentary/ page up with it if you want to see. What's great is that videos actually show up when I added your code, but without it they're gone completely :/

Comment: Ok! So I figured out why the documentary and corporate page templates weren't pulling the post meta: my meta fields id's in `functions.php` had a variable `@prefix` applied before the name. I added that prefix and, voilá! My question still, though, is why the homepage template was working at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for an answer:

My meta fields id's in `functions.php` had a variable `@prefix` applied before the name. I added that prefix on the template and, voile!

Still unsure why my homepage template was working correctly with the wrong meta id's, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end.