# Custom meta boxes ID prefix showing on first category but not others

Tags: categories, metabox, post-meta, oembed

I've created a custom post type and added some custom meta boxes using this great resource: https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress

The problem, I've found, is that the post meta fields have a different `id` depending on whether the post is from the first category of type or not. I had had a problem pulling the post meta on a page template because of it, here: [New WP_query in template not working with CPT+category on some pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161107/new-wp-query-in-template-not-working-with-cptcategory-on-some-pages), resulting in having to reference a different meta box `id` for different page templates, depending on the category I was pulling.

Not a huge deal, but it now brings me to my current situation: Pulling thumbnails from oembedded videos and setting them as the featured image automatically, using this fantastic plugin, [Featured Image of Video from oembed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70752/featured-image-of-video-from-oembed), works on that first category, but none of the others. It has to be related somehow, right?

Here's my custom meta box code:

```
//Initialize the meta boxes
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes', 9999 );   
function wpt_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes() {

if ( ! class_exists( 'cmb_Meta_Box' ) )
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/metaboxes/init.php';
}

//add custom fields
add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes' , 'wpt_create_metaboxes' );
function wpt_create_metaboxes( $meta_boxes ) {

// Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
$prefix = '_cmb_';

//Films details meta boxes
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id' => 'film_contents',
'title' => 'Films',
'pages' => array('films'),//Add our post_type() we created earlier.
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'low',
'show_names' => true,
'fields' => array(
    array(    //Add video embed field
    'name' => 'Film URL',
    'desc' => 'Enter a youtube or vimeo URL. Supports services listed at <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds">http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds</a>.',
    'id' => $prefix .'film_embed',
    'type' => 'oembed',
    ),
    array(    //Add a text area
    'name' => 'Film Description',
    'desc' => 'A few words about the film.',
    'std' => '',
    'id' => $prefix .'film_textarea',
    'type' => 'textarea',
    ),
)
);
return $meta_boxes;
}
```

Here's my modified "Featured Image from oembed" code to work with my meta box:

```
/**
* Plugin Name: oEmbed Featured Image
* Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70752/1685
* Description: Automatically set the featured image if an oEmbed-compatible embed is found in the post content.
* Version: 1.0
* Author: TheDeadMedic
* Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1685/thedeadmedic
*
* @package oEmbed_Featured_Image
*/

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', array( 'ofi', 'init' ) );

/**
* @package oEmbed_Featured_Image
*/
class ofi
{
/**
 * The post thumbnail ID
 *
 * @var int
 */
private $_thumb_id;

/**
 * The post ID
 *
 * @var int
 */
private $_post_id;

/**
 * Sets up an instance if called statically, and attempts to set the featured
 * image from an embed in the post content (if one has not already been set).
 *
 * @param  int $post_id
 * @return object|null
 */
public function init( $post_id )
{
    if ( ! isset( $this ) )
        return new ofi( $post_id );

    global $wp_embed;

    $this->_post_id = absint( $post_id );

    if ( ! $this->_thumb_id = get_post_meta( $this->_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true ) ) {
        if ( $content = get_post_field( 'film_embed', $this->_post_id, 'raw' ) ) {

            add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );
            $wp_embed->autoembed( $content );
            remove_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );

        }
    }
}

/**
 * @see init()
 */
public function __construct( $post_id )
{
    $this->init( $post_id );
}

/**
 * Callback for the "oembed_dataparse" hook, which will fire on a successful
 * response from the oEmbed provider.
 *
 * @see WP_oEmbed::data2html()
 *
 * @param string $return The embed HTML
 * @param object $data   The oEmbed response
 * @param string $url    The oEmbed content URL
 */
public function oembed_dataparse( $return, $data, $url )
{
    if ( ! empty( $data->thumbnail_url ) && ! $this->_thumb_id ) {
        // if ( in_array( @ $data->type, array( 'video' ) ) ) // Only set for video embeds
            $this->set_thumb_by_url( $data->thumbnail_url, @ $data->title );
    }
}

/**
 * Attempt to download the image from the URL, add it to the media library,
 * and set as the featured image.
 *
 * @see media_sideload_image()
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param string $title Optionally set attachment title
 */
public function set_thumb_by_url( $url, $title = null )
{
    /* Following assets will already be loaded if in admin */
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';

    $temp = download_url( $url );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $temp ) && $info = @ getimagesize( $temp ) ) {
        if ( ! strlen( $title ) )
            $title = null;

        if ( ! $ext = image_type_to_extension( $info[2] ) )
            $ext = '.jpg';

        $data = array(
            'name'     => md5( $url ) . $ext,
            'tmp_name' => $temp,
        );

        $id = media_handle_sideload( $data, $this->_post_id, $title );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $id ) )
            return update_post_meta( $this->_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $this->_thumb_id = $id );
    }

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $temp ) )
        @ unlink( $temp );
}
}
```

I tried modifying this part (from directly above):

```
if ( $content = get_post_field( 'film_embed', $this->_post_id, 'raw' ) ) {

    add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );
    $wp_embed->autoembed( $content );
    remove_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );

}
```

...like this to include the possibility of the `_cmb_` prefix to `film_embed`:

```
if ( $content = get_post_field( 'film_embed', $this->_post_id, 'raw' ) || $content = get_post_field( '_cmb_film_embed', $this->_post_id, 'raw' ) ) {

    add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );
    $wp_embed->autoembed( $content );
    remove_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', array( $this, 'oembed_dataparse' ), 10, 3 );

}
```

...but it didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this stems from your use of [get_post_field()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field), which is reserved for fields found in the posts table of the database (ie: built-in to WordPress, rather than custom fields). For custom fields you should use [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).